# AIR: new window...adding content to it doesnt show up

Tags: apache-flex, air

OK I created a class called WindowManager, so far it just as 1 method, to create a new window. You pass the DisplayObject to it that should be contained in the window. The problem is if I added a newly created display object to the new window it does not show up. However if I first as the new display object to the main window, then try to add it to the new window it works right.

here is this class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.NativeWindow;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowSystemChrome;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowType;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.display.Screen;

    public class WindowManager
    {
        public function WindowManager()
        {
        }

        public function newWindow(content:DisplayObject):void
        {
            var windowOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
            windowOptions.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE;
            windowOptions.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;
            windowOptions.transparent = true;

            var newWindow:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(windowOptions);
            newWindow.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            newWindow.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            newWindow.bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, content.width, content.height);


            newWindow.title = "New Window Number 2";
            newWindow.alwaysInFront = true;

            newWindow.x = (Screen.mainScreen.bounds.width - newWindow.bounds.width)/2;
            newWindow.y = (Screen.mainScreen.bounds.height - newWindow.bounds.height)/2;


            newWindow.stage.addChild(content);

            newWindow.activate();
        }

    }
}
```

If I call it like this:

```
var notifierBox:NotifierBox = new NotifierBox();
new WindowManager().newWindow(notifierBox);
```

The new window will contain nothing..but If I add the dispay object to the main window before trying to add it to the new window it works fine:

```
var notifierBox:NotifierBox = new NotifierBox();
addChild(notifierBox);
new WindowManager().newWindow(notifierBox);
```

Can someone tell me why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/NativeWindow.html says:

> Content can be added to a window using the DisplayObjectContainer methods of the Stage object such as addChild().
>
> You cannot not add Flex components directly to the display list of a NativeWindow instance. Instead, use the Flex mx:WindowedApplication and mx:Window components to create your windows and add the other Flex components as children of those objects. [...]

Maybe you could try the Window class instead of the NativeWindow?